# Prevent alert on browser back in rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, forms, sweetalert

I have a form in html and on submit the request is forwarded to an action in a controller which registers a new user. On successful registration it redirects to another action in the same controller(sometimes different controller) where I alert a welcome message using `sweet alert 2 gem`. When the user navigates to another page after welcome message and presses the back button in the browser, it again alerts the welcome message. How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

You may set a cookie variable to know wether the user was on this page before.

Something like this: `cookies[:alert] = false`

And on the page before the alert, you reset this variable to `true`, like this, he won't see this alert unless he comes from the page before.